# Can we use set objectstore name dynamically?

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

I am using Dixie.js in my application, below is the piece of code to create a DB & a object store

```
import Dexie from "dexie";

const db = new Dexie("sampledb");
db.version(1).stores({ tasks: "++id" });
```

Instead of hard codeed table/objectstore name task, can we use some variable's value like below

```
const sessionId = "SEEE-123456";
db.version(1).stores({ sessionId: "++id" });
```

Could not find any option in their official documentation. I will appreciated for any help/input.

Thanks!

Comment: { [variable]: "++id" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In modern javascript you can declare objects with dynamic property names:

```
const tableName = "yourDynamicTableName";
db.version(1).stores({ [tableName]: "++id" });
```